# Is it possible to get to the end of the list in vba?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am wondering if it is possible to get to the end of the list in vba? For example, I have a document with manual numbering and autonumbering in word.
Now, I would like to apply styles. But, when applying styles to auto - numbered list the numbering would be removed upon applying another style. So, to overcome this problem I am wondering if it is possible to get to the end of the list. So, that I would convert autonumbering into manual number and apply the formatting.

```
Sub applyformatting()
pos2 = Selection.Range.End
pos1 = Selection.Range.Start
Dim i As Integer, para As Paragraph
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs.Count
Set para = ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs(i)
    If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListBullet Or para.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListSimpleNumbering Then
    ' Goto the end of the list and do the following until it reaches current paragraphs
        Do Until Selection.Range.Start = pos1
            Selection.MoveUp wdParagraph, 1
            para.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
            para.Range.Style = "tt"
        Loop
    Else
        para.Range.Style = "t"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why aren't you applying numbered styles, e.g. List Bullet and List Number?

Comment: That would be a great idea, but I would need to restart the list and there are different lists because of that I thought it would be easier to deal with the above method if any way to get to the end of the list is figured out.